# Regex to remove specific words in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to do the some manipulation using regex in python.

So input is  `+1223,+12_remove_me,+222,+2223_remove_me`
and 
output should be `+1223,+222`

Output should only contain comma seperated words which don't contain `_remove_me` and only one comma between each word.

**Note**: REGEX which I tried `\+([0-9|+]*)_` , `\+([0-9|+]*)` and some other combination using which I did not get required output.

**Note 2** I can't use loop, need to do that without loop with regex only.

Comment: Just for curiosity, can I ask you why do you use `regex` instead of `re`?

Comment: Perhaps, [`r',?\+\d+(?:_[^_,]+)+'`](https://regex101.com/r/tN2fV9/2), or just [`,?\+\d+_[^,]+`](https://regex101.com/r/tN2fV9/3)

Comment: Check [this demo](https://ideone.com/l3t7B1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew we need to remove space between `,`

Comment: What space? The result is `+1223,+222`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, you are right! Perhaps you should post this as answer.

Comment: Posted, please check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex seems incomplete, but you were on the right track. Note that  a pipe symbol inside a character class is treated as a literal and your `[0-9|+]` matches a digit or a `|` or a `+` symbols.

You may use

```
,?\+\d+_[^,]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tN2fV9/3)

Explanation:

- `,?` - optional `,` (if the "word" is at the beginning of the string, it should be optional)
- `\+` - a literal `+`
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `_` - a literal underscore
- `[^,]+` - 1+ characters other than `,`

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/l3t7B1):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r',?\+\d+_[^,]+')
test_str = "+1223,+12_remove_me,+222,+2223_remove_me"
result = p.sub("", test_str)
print(result)
# => +1223,+222
```

Comment: Won't this break if no numbers precede the '_remove_me'?
Also won't it leave a leading comma?
See https://ideone.com/RINN5W

Comment: @TomRees: Judging by the sample OP input there no leading commas and no entries without leading digits. There are no exact requirements, I deduced them from the patterns OP tried. Actually, removing leading and trailing commas is easy: `r',+$|^,+'` (a second step will be required, or a much longer expression with alternatives). As for the digits, the `*` quantifier can be used after `\d`: [`,?\+\d*_[^,]+`](https://regex101.com/r/tN2fV9/4)

Comment: Agreed - Have my +1. Just thought I'd point it out in case the OPs examples weren't complete.

Comment: Ah yes, in Python removing leading/trailing chars is easy with `strip`. However, OP needs a regex. Let's hear from the OP.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but output is wrong when input is `+12_remove_me,+222,+2223_remove_me`

Comment: @Pramod: If you really have to do all that with 1 regex, you can use [`r'^(?:\+\d+_[^,]+)+,?|,\+\d+_[^,]+'`](https://regex101.com/r/oA5hQ1/1). See [this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/UxsfUt).

Answer (score 1):

A *non-regex* approach would involve using [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and excluding items ending with `_remove_me`:

```
>>> s = "+1223,+12_remove_me,+222,+2223_remove_me"
>>> items = [item for item in s.split(",") if not item.endswith("_remove_me")]
>>> items
['+1223', '+222']
```

Or, if `_remove_me` can be present anywhere inside each item, use `not in`:

```
>>> items = [item for item in s.split(",") if "_remove_me" not in item]
>>> items
['+1223', '+222']
```

You can then use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join the items into a string again:

```
>>> ",".join(items)
'+1223,+222'
```

Comment: we can't use loop, need to do that with regex only.

Comment: @Pramod hm, could you please elaborate why?

Comment: @alexce because my internal compiling system supports regex based manipulation only.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need regex with negotiation

```
[^(_remove_me)]
```

[Demo](http://pythex.org/?regex=[%5E%28_remove_me%29]&test_string=%2B1223%2C%2B12_remove_me%2C%2B222%2C%2B2223_remove_me&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Answer (score 0):

You could perform this without a regex, just using string manipulation. The following can be written as a one-liner, but has been expanded for readability.

```
my_string = '+1223,+12_remove_me,+222,+2223_remove_me' #define string
my_list = my_string.split(',')                         #create a list of words
my_list = [word for word in my_list if '_remove_me' not in word] #stop here if you want a list of words
output_string = ','.join(my_list)
```

Comment: I can not use loop at all, I need to do than using regular expression only.