# Remove some specific text from an input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
say_d = ["say", "tell me"]
a = input("Please Type An Action For Me To Do: ")
if any(word in a for word in say_d):
    print(a)
```

This is the program that prints out the typed input, if any keyword from `say_d` is in it. But it will also print the keyword. Is there any way to remove the keyword from the supposed output? Like:

```
say_d = ["say", "tell me"]
a = input("Please Type An Action For Me To Do: ")
if any(word in a for word in say_d):
    print(a-say_d)
```

Comment: give sample input/output

Comment: Because you've used `any` you don't know, inside the `if` block, *which* keyword matched. If you `for` looped over `say_d` until you reached a matching keyword, then you'd know which one and be able to `str.replace` it with nothing. This also means you don't have to loop over the whole of `say_d` if it matches the first trigger word.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to remove specific words in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311931/regex-to-remove-specific-words-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either regex or `str.replace` to replace the common words with empty string:

```
import re
say_d = ["say","tell me"]
a = (input("Please Type An Action For Me To Do: "))
if any(word in a for word in say_d):
    print(re.sub('|\b'.join(say_d), '', a))
```

But Note that if you want to remove the common words if thery exist in input, you don't need to use `any`, for both functions (`re.sub` and `str.replace`) replace the string only of they exist in your text.

Also, the part `word in a` will check the membership within the entire input string, not its words. That says, if one of the words within the input string is contain a word inside `say_d` it will return True. Like `sayulita` which is contain the word `say`.

For getting ride of this problem you can again check the membership by splitting the input string and then looping over it or use regex.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you looking for:

```
say_d=["say","tell me"]
a=(input("Please Type An Action For Me To Do: "))
if any(word in a for word in say_d):
  set2 = set(say_d)
  result = [element for element in a if element not in set2]
  print(list(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any input and output in question, i assume that you want to remove any candidate word(which in list say_d) from input string, so maybe it can be as simple as below:

> ```
> say_d=["say","tell me"]
> a=(input("Please Type An Action For Me To Do: "))
> ret = reduce(lambda r, w: r.replace(w, ''), say_d, a)
> if len(ret) != len(a):
>   print ret
> ```